# iPhone 5 Bit Depth & Sample Rate?

Tags: iphone, field-recording, bit-depth, sample-rate, gear

So, are we expecting the newly released **iPhone 5** to have an increase in Bit Depth & Sample Rate capabilities for audio recording software / hardware?

I scoured the tech specs on Apple's website but couldn't find info on this topic (I assume it is hidden in the developer manuals).

I understand that the 'new' iPad is capable of recording **24bit/96kHz** using apps such as **[auria](http://auriaapp.com/Products/auria)**.

I'd love to see **Tascam** ([ixz](http://tascam.com/product/ixz/)) or **Apogee** ([JAM](http://www.apogeedigital.com/products/jam.php)) release a quality preamp with +48v capable of recording 24 bit/96kHz audio to an iOS app for field recording purposes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this as well. An iPad with a good preamp recording 24/96 would be a fantastic way to record foley in the field if you need to keep it portable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, rode has created the solution to this problem.

The iXY iPhone/iPad microphone, with its own a/d converter can record at 96kHz/24bit, bypassing iOS's 48kHz/16bit limit.

Great move from Rode.

http://store.rodemic.com/products/ixy

Not for iPhone 5 yet, however.